# R: How to get rid of NA in correlation

Tags: r, correlation, na

I got my correlation values like this. (Using `COR<-cor(mytest[sapply(mytest,is.numeric)])`

```
          AGE      SALARY    REGION

AGE        1          NA       0.25
SALARY     NA          1
REGION     0.25        NA        1
```

Problem is correlation above gives me NA's if a column has at least on NA. I tried to get rid of it using `> COR<-cor(mytest[sapply(mytest,is.numeric)],use="complete.obs")`

But it does not seem to work, giving me "no complete element pairs" error. Please show me how to deal with those.

Note that its a big data frame, and it actually has not only 3 col and 3 row, but many more, so I can't calculate correlations separately. Would be too time consuming. I believe there is a shorter way.
Many thanks

Comment: Please show some example dataset that produce this result.  Also, have you tried with other options in `use`

Comment: You don't give the full error message, but what you quote seems self-explaining.

Comment: @akrun, i tried use = "everything" which doesnt work either. My data has 1000 rows, representing different people and 36 columns, representing different values, regarding each person, like AGE, SALARY, REGION, GENDER etc. I needed to calculate cor between each column, so I used that formula above, and got that table with correlations and NA's shown above.

Comment: @akrun i think I got it! I tried use = "pairwise.complete.obs". looks like it worked :)

Comment: It's entirely possible that the correlation is NA

Comment: `cor(1, 1)` is NA.  I'm saying that it might be calculated to be NA

Comment: @RichardScriven yeah I get it, but in my case, with my data it should be something else. It gave me like 1000 NA's out of 1260, means something is wrong